# cant get ESelect2 extension in yii concatenate two or more columns in the dropdown

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii, html-select, yii-extensions

Eselect2 is the extension am using and myADropDown() fetches the data and displays but then my need is concatenate two or more columns in the dropdown

model1 view

```
     <?php $this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2', array(
      'name' => 'id',
    'model' => $model,
    'options'  => array(
'placeholder' => $model->getAttributeLabel('id'),
  ),
   'data' => $model->myADropDown(),


      ));?>
```

model1

```
  public function getConcatened()
      {
        return $this->name.' '.$this->locate.' '.$this->rating;
      }

     public function myADropDown()
  {
    $vid=Yii::app()->SESSION['vid'];

  $gid=Model2::model()->xyz($vid);

     $list=CHtml::listData($gid,'id','concatened');
 return $list;
    }
```

// id is fk in another tbl

in the **dropdownlist my need is name ,location,rating for each person** , am unable to do so

Please Let me know how do i achieve it

Answer (score 0):

For concatenating the table fields in listdata, Please check this Yii forum answer:

[Link](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/12855-concatenate-strings-in-chtmllistdata/page__view__findpost__p__179908)

As per the link suggestion, you need to add a function in model to get concatenated string.

```
 public function __get($key){
                $action = 'get'.str_replace(' ','',ucwords(str_replace('_',' ',$key)));
                if(method_exists($this, $action)) return $this->$action();
                return parent::__get($key);
        }
```

Comment: no its not working as well am using eselect2 as extension for which i need

Comment: It's not issue with eselect2. You are preparing data from listdata. So you need to work in model only. not in eselect.